# Jenkins Ant Integration

Tags: jenkins, ant

When I use Ant build tools with Jenkins. Do I have to use build.xml file in Jenkins as well as in eclipse?

My Jenkin's url is in remote server. It is installed with Ant. Do I also need to install Ant build tool in my local pc?

I am using repository to none. It means source file will come from local PC.
  Please correct me if anything wrong with my understanding.

Comment: You need to know the basics first. And try to limit your question to one problem. You are asking 3 questions in 1.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins would need to access your sources (using the URL of a source repository -- git, mercurial, SVN, ... -- where you would push your work) in order to execute a command.

If that command is ant, that means build.xml must be part of your sources in order for Jenkins to execute ant in the workspace created for the job execution.

And to test that build.xml locally, you need ant as well on your PC.

Comment: I don't git or SVN repository. Only Remote Jenkin's url and local pc. Could I communicate my local pc with remote jenkin's server. It means push work to local pc.

Comment: @snoor A Jenkins URL is just for executing jobs. In order to have files for that job to execture, you need a repository URL. Or at the very least a path (local path or network shared path) where to find the files.